# Add bill to pay to existing batch payment via API

Tags: xero-api

I am planning on sending bills to pay (outstanding invoices) to Xero from Business Central in a batch payment so that users can produce an ABA file from Xero but have a couple of questions:

1. Is a batch payment what I should be creating, I cannot find any else in the API references?
2. I have not tested this yet, but are you able to include/exclude bills to pay in an existing batch payment via API?

Thanks,
Rod

I have tried creating normal payments, but these are just for one per invoice and it is my understanding that these cannot be exported in an ABA file?

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to remove particular payments from a batch. You would need to delete the batch and create a new one with the bills you want to pay

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Is a batch payment the correct kind of record to create via API to be able to produce an ABA file in Xero?